ChromaDB query documents by datetime
I'm working on some app where I want to query chat conversations I added to ChromaDB.
Each line in such conversation has the following structure:
timestamp - user name - text
I've exported all text and pushed it into ChromaDB
I'm using upsert method as follows (after dividing the text into chunks):
        for index, chunk in enumerate(chunks):
            embed = ollama.embeddings(model=self.EMBED_MODEL, prompt=chunk)['embedding']
            self.collection.upsert([source_name + str(index)], [embed],
                                   documents=[chunk], metadatas={"source": source_name})

My next goal was, based on a query, I want to pull the relevant data and ask an LLM some questions about it, but there's a problem in "time related" queries.
For example: "Summarize what happened in the last 2 days"
While the LLM does its job fairly well, the problem is ChromaDB is feeding with irrelevant documents.
For instance: sometimes it brings it data from last month or 2 months and not the last 2 days.
I wonder if there's a best practice for how I should store the data in ChromaDB so I would be able to query it the way I intend to.
Note:
I'm currently querying a specific document (which is fine), and n_result=1
